# how to compare two image backgrounds directly in android

Tags: android, image, compare

hi i am doing one app here  i need to comapre image backgrounds.when ,images background diffrent means i need to flip those images,images background same means i need to stop animation. i tried using below code but i flip images. but i dont know how to stop those images flip animation when images background same that time. here i need to give custom background so taken 6 imageviews for 3 images.please any one help me....

```
filpanimatedexample .class:
public class filpanimatedexample extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    RelativeLayout layout,layout1;
    ImageView imageViewFlip,imageViewOriginal,imageViewFlip1,imageViewOriginal1,imageViewFlip2,imageViewOriginal2;
    FlipAnimator animator,animator1,animator2,animator3,animator4,animator5;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        imageViewOriginal = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageViewFlip = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageViewOriginal1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        imageViewFlip1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        imageViewOriginal2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        imageViewFlip2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        imageViewOriginal.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageViewFlip.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageViewOriginal1.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageViewFlip1.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageViewOriginal2.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageViewFlip2.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(v==imageViewOriginal)
        {
            animator = new FlipAnimator(imageViewOriginal, imageViewFlip,
                    imageViewFlip.getWidth() / 2, imageViewFlip.getHeight() / 2);
            if (imageViewOriginal.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                animator.reverse();
            }
            imageViewOriginal.startAnimation(animator);
        }
        if(v==imageViewFlip)
        {
            animator1 = new FlipAnimator(imageViewFlip, imageViewOriginal,
                    imageViewOriginal.getWidth() / 2, imageViewOriginal.getHeight() / 2);
            if (imageViewFlip.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                animator1.reverse();
            }

            imageViewOriginal.startAnimation(animator1);


        }
        if(v==imageViewOriginal1)
        {
            animator2 = new FlipAnimator(imageViewOriginal1, imageViewFlip1,
                    imageViewFlip1.getWidth() / 2, imageViewFlip1.getHeight() / 2);
            if (imageViewOriginal1.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                animator2.reverse();
            }

            imageViewOriginal1.startAnimation(animator2);

        }
        if(v==imageViewFlip1)
        {
            animator3 = new FlipAnimator(imageViewFlip1, imageViewOriginal1,
                    imageViewOriginal1.getWidth() / 2, imageViewOriginal1.getHeight() / 2);
            if (imageViewFlip1.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                animator3.reverse();
            }

            imageViewOriginal1.startAnimation(animator3);

        }
        if(v==imageViewOriginal2)
        {
            animator4 = new FlipAnimator(imageViewOriginal2, imageViewFlip2,
                    imageViewFlip2.getWidth() / 2, imageViewFlip2.getHeight() /   2);
            if (imageViewOriginal2.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                animator4.reverse();
            }

            imageViewOriginal2.startAnimation(animator4);

        }
        if(v==imageViewFlip2)
        {
            animator5 = new FlipAnimator(imageViewFlip2, imageViewOriginal2,
                    imageViewOriginal2.getWidth() / 2,  imageViewOriginal2.getHeight() / 2);
            if (imageViewFlip2.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                animator5.reverse();
            }

            imageViewOriginal2.startAnimation(animator5);
        }

    }
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/icon11" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/icon11" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/icon3" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/icon11" >
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: sorry, didn't bother to read/try out code. but first things first: were you able to successfully compare the backgrounds?

Comment: Object tag = imageViewOriginal.getTag();
     int backgroundId = R.drawable.icon;
  if( tag != null && ((Integer)tag).intValue() == backgroundId){
    
  imageViewOriginal.clearAnimation();
  }  i compare in this way but i dnt know it correct or not.its not working.

Comment: Try this... getResources().getBackgroundDrwable(elementID);

Answer (score 0):

Try change Drawable to Bitmap objects

```
Bitmap bitmap = ...;
Bitmap bitmap1 = ...;

if(bitmap == bitmap2)
{
    //Your Toasts
}
```

An example of convert:

```
Drawable myDraw = view.getBackground();
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)myDraw).getBitmap();
```

Comment: here in myDraw any background is  not there. it contains value null

Answer (score 0):

```
 i1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 i2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

 Drawable d=i1.getDrawable();
 Drawable d1=i2.getDrawable();
 if( d == d1){
     Toast.makeText(Example.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }else {
    Toast.makeText(Example.this, "hai", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Comment: hi tried in this way also but i am not getting any toast meesage

Comment: here d,d2 contain diffrent values

Comment: those imageviews have images or not.

Comment: are you getting values for drawable.

Comment: in this drawable value is null.but i convert that drawable to bitmaps then i compare those bitmaps.now its is working

Comment: set it as the answer with changes , that will be use for others